# Booting Clonezilla from a live USB on a MacBook running Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, macbook, clonezilla, liveusb

I have Ubuntu 10.04 running on a MacBook Pro 5.5. It's using [rEFIt](http://refit.sourceforge.net/) to allow Ubuntu to boot via GRUB despite the Mac's EFI. For backup purposes, I'd like to clone it's hard drive using [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/). I followed the [instructions](http://clonezilla.org/liveusb.php#windows-method-a) from the official Clonezilla website to create a live USB using the Clonezilla ISO and Tuxboot, however booting the Mac while the live USB is attached has no effect. Holding down the Option key during booting shows no additional drives, and bringing up the rEFIt screens also shows only the Ubuntu partition, and the original Mac OS X partition.

How do I make a live Clonezilla media that's bootable from a Mac running Linux?

Comment: I'd love to know the answer to this as well.  I'm having trouble with creating a LiveUSB for Fedora.

Comment: @Eric B., Upon further reading, LiveUSB for Macs is not well supported, since recent Macs use a different booting mechanism. I found a couple blog posts explaining how to do it, but it was incredibly involved and a bit hackish.

Comment: @Cerin: Can u use this method for creating the LiveUSB http://penguintosh.com/tag/linux-usb-creator/

Comment: @EricB. Can u use this method for creating the LiveUSB http://penguintosh.com/tag/linux-usb-creator/

Comment: Maybe you could add the USB to GRUB and then pick it in the Grub boot menu Grub
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=992426 Grub2+Plop
http://www.plop.at/en/bootmanager/mbrinstall.html#grub2inst

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was never able to solve this. I ended up simply tarballing my filesystem to an external firewire drive. It doesn't create a perfect copy, but in some ways it's much more convenient than having to reboot into a live USB.